# Qt QColor get color code like 45653 (0-65535)

Tags: qt, qt4, qcolor

I have a simple problem but I can't solve it yet.

I hame something like this:

```
QColor someColor = getColor();
```

After this I need to get color code that in range (0-65535), I pay your attention that I don't need color codes in range (0-255).

So what I must to do?
Maybe something like:

```
someColor.get...()
```

Answer (score 1):

QColor is a combination of 3 bytes (RGB), so you should be looking for a color range from 0 to 2^24-1 [0, 16777215]

You could do something like:

```
bool ok;
qDebug() << someColor.name().replace("#", "").toUInt(&ok,16);
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Qt already provides such function. 
See documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#rgb) and [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#QRgb-typedef).

What it says:

```
QRgb QColor::rgb() const
// Returns the RGB value of the color. The alpha value is opaque.

QRgb QColor::rgba() const
// Returns the RGB value of the color, including its alpha.

typedef QRgb
// An ARGB quadruplet on the format #AARRGGBB, equivalent to an unsigned int.
// The type also holds a value for the alpha-channel.
```